# How to use pyodide function more one times

Tags: webassembly, pyodide

I want run funcion to stemm each row of a table. I want do it after of HTML code is loaded, I try this

```
<body>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/dev/full/pyodide.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
      async function main(kw) {
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide({
          indexURL: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/dev/full/",
        });
        
        pyodide.globals.set("mikw", kw);     
        await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip");
        await pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
            
        import micropip
        import js
        await micropip.install('snowballstemmer')
        import snowballstemmer
        stemmer = snowballstemmer.stemmer('english')
        
        div = js.document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML = stemmer.stemWords('Hello this my default text '.split())
        js.document.body.prepend(div)
        varP = js.document.getElementById('origen').textContent
        print(varP)
        salida = stemmer.stemWords(varP.split())
        print(salida)
        divSalida = js.document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML =salida
        salida = stemmer.stemWords(mikw.split())
        print(salida)

        `);
        
      } 
        
      main('This are the second text, I put this text on arguments function');
    </script>
    <div id="origen" >This text is inside of HTML element</div>
 </body>
```

The output is

```
['This', 'text', 'is', 'insid', 'of', 'HTML', 'element']
['This', 'are', 'the', 'second', 'text,', 'I', 'put', 'this', 'text', 'on', 'argument', 'function']
```

But I can't (or I don't know) use function to stemm other kws after load html, for example after load DOM (to get values of my HTML table and run each)

```
....      
<div id="origen" onclick="temp()">This text is inside of HTML element</div>
   <script>
     myNewkwStemm=main('other word');
     myNewkwStemm2=main('word2');
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are loading Pyodide multiple times by including the `loadPyodide` call in the main function, which gives an error for your subsequent `main` calls. Move  `loadPyodide` outside `main` should resolve the issue:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  let initPyodide = loadPyodide({
    indexURL: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/dev/full/",
  })
  async function main(kw) {
    let pyodide = await initPyodide
    // ... other code
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n8xjsp6/)

Also you probably do not want to rely on `pyodide.globals` to pass the argument in, it leads to a race condition since you are running everything asynchronously.